# Learning about developing OS

Tags: operating-system

I like to learn OS development from the scratch(About Interrupt handling, about IDT, how to load my own boot sector,etc)
Can you please recommend some resources ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OSDev wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Expanded_Main_Page) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Operating System Design and Implementation](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Operating-Systems-Design-Implementation-Tanenbaum/dp/0135053765/ref=sr_1_4?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1343027781&sr=1-4) by Andrew Tanenbaum. It contains the source to an operating system call Minix and was the "inspiration" for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The best online ressources are on [OSdev Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page). You will find all the info you need to start with kernel crafting, from toolchain to IDT filling.